# How to deploy django project and postgreSQL from localhost to Digital ocean

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, digital-ocean

I have developed django project on my computer. I used virtuelenv and installed all libraries and packages there. I also have postgreSQL database on my computer. How could I deploy my existing server with all files and libraries, my postgreSQL database with all tables and all rows to digitalocean. I only found tutorials on how to create new django projects on digitalocean.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is plenty of tutorials and documentation for doing this.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/django?type=tutorials

In the other hand you only have to migrate your data base from your computer to your new server. Maybe you should check [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html)